# Merging data frames with different number of rows and different columns

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, cbind

I have two data frames with different number of columns and rows. I want to combine them into one data frame.

```
> month.saf
   Name NCDC    Year    Month   Day HrMn    Temp    Q
244 AP  99999   2014    2       1   0      12       1
245 AP  99999   2014    2       1   300    12.2     1
246 AP  99999   2014    2       1   600    14.4     1
247 AP  99999   2014    2       1   900    18.6     1
248 AP  99999   2014    2       1   1200   18       1
249 AP  99999   2014    2       1   1500   13.6     1
250 AP  99999   2014    2       1   1800   11.8     1
251 AP  99999   2014    2       1   2100   10.8     1
252 AP  99999   2014    2       2   0      8.4      1
253 AP  99999   2014    2       2   300    8.6      1
254 AP  99999   2014    2       2   600    19.8     2
255 AP  99999   2014    2       2   900    22.8     1
256 AP  99999   2014    2       2   1200   20.8     1
257 AP  99999   2014    2       2   1500   16.4     1
258 AP  99999   2014    2       2   1800   13.4     1
259 AP  99999   2014    2       2   2100   12.4     1
> T2Mdf
                    V1               V2
0     293.494262695312 291.642639160156
300   294.003479003906 292.375091552734
600   296.809997558594 295.207885742188
900   298.287811279297 297.181549072266
1200  298.317565917969 297.725708007813
1500  298.134002685547 296.226165771484
1800  296.006805419922 293.354248046875
2100  293.785491943359 293.547210693359
0.1   294.638732910156 293.019866943359
300.1 292.179992675781 291.256958007812
```

The output that I want is like this:

```
    Name    NCDC    Year    Month   Day HrMn    Temp    Q   V1          V2
244 AP  99999   2014        2       1   0       12      1   293.4942627 291.6426392
245 AP  99999   2014        2       1   300     12.2    1   294.003479  292.3750916
246 AP  99999   2014        2       1   600     14.4    1   296.8099976 295.2078857
247 AP  99999   2014        2       1   900     18.6    1   298.2878113 297.1815491
248 AP  99999   2014        2       1   1200    18      1   298.3175659 297.725708
249 AP  99999   2014        2       1   1500    13.6    1   298.1340027 296.2261658
250 AP  99999   2014        2       1   1800    11.8    1   296.0068054 293.354248
251 AP  99999   2014        2       1   2100    10.8    1   293.7854919 293.5472107
252 AP  99999   2014        2       2   0       8.4     1   294.6387329 293.0198669
253 AP  99999   2014        2       2   300     8.6     1   292.1799927 291.256958
254 AP  99999   2014        2       2   600     19.8    2   292.2477417 291.3471069
255 AP  99999   2014        2       2   900     22.8    1   294.2276306 294.2766418
256 AP  99999   2014        2       2   1200    20.8    1   NA          NA
257 AP  99999   2014        2       2   1500    16.4    1   NA          NA
258 AP  99999   2014        2       2   1800    13.4    1   NA          NA
259 AP  99999   2014        2       2   2100    12.4    1   NA          NA
```

I tried `cbind`but it gives me an error

> Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :    arguments imply
>   differing number of rows: 216, 220

And using `rbind.fill()` but it gives me something like

```
V1               V2                     Name        USAF  NCDC Year Month Day HrMn  I   Type QCP Temp  Q
    1  293.494262695312 291.642639160156       <NA>     NA    NA   NA    NA  NA   NA    NA  <NA>  NA <NA> NA
    2  294.003479003906 292.375091552734       <NA>     NA    NA   NA    NA  NA   NA    NA  <NA>  NA <NA> NA
    3  296.809997558594 295.207885742188       <NA>     NA    NA   NA    NA  NA   NA    NA  <NA>  NA <NA> NA
    4  298.287811279297 297.181549072266       <NA>     NA    NA   NA    NA  NA   NA    NA  <NA>  NA <NA> NA
    5  298.317565917969 297.725708007813       <NA>     NA    NA   NA    NA  NA   NA    NA  <NA>  NA <NA> NA
    6              <NA>             <NA>        AP  421820 99999 2014     2   1    0    4   FM-12 NA   12  1
    7              <NA>             <NA>        AP  421820 99999 2014     2   1  300    4   FM-12 NA 12.2  1
    8              <NA>             <NA>        AP  421820 99999 2014     2   1  600    4   FM-12 NA 14.4  1
    9              <NA>             <NA>        AP  421820 99999 2014     2   1  900    4   FM-12 NA 18.6  1
    10             <NA>             <NA>        AP  421820 99999 2014     2   1 1200    4   FM-12 NA   18  1
```

How is it possible to do this in R?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If A and B are the two input data frames, here are some solutions:

**1) merge**  This solutions works regardless of whether A or B has more rows.

```
merge(data.frame(A, row.names=NULL), data.frame(B, row.names=NULL), 
  by = 0, all = TRUE)[-1]
```

The first two arguments could be replaced with just A and B respectively if A and B have default rownames, i.e. 1, 2, ..., or if they have consistent  rownames.  That is, `merge(A, B, by = 0, all = TRUE)[-1]` .

For example, if we have this input:

```
# test inputs
A <- data.frame(BOD, row.names = letters[1:6])
B <- setNames(2 * BOD[1:2, ], c("X", "Y"))
```

then:

```
merge(data.frame(A, row.names=NULL), data.frame(B, row.names=NULL), 
  by = 0, all = TRUE)[-1]
```

gives:

```
  Time demand  X    Y
1    1    8.3  2 16.6
2    2   10.3  4 20.6
3    3   19.0 NA   NA
4    4   16.0 NA   NA
5    5   15.6 NA   NA
6    7   19.8 NA   NA
```

**1a)** An equivalent variation is:

```
do.call("merge", c(lapply(list(A, B), data.frame, row.names=NULL), 
  by = 0, all = TRUE))[-1]
```

**2) cbind.zoo**  This solution assumes that A has more rows and that B's entries are all of the same type, e.g. all numeric.  A is not restricted.  These conditions hold in the data of the question.

```
library(zoo)
data.frame(A, cbind(zoo(, 1:nrow(A)), as.zoo(B)))
```