# Merge 2 dataframes with all.x = TRUE (except for NA's in x) in R

Tags: r, dataframe, join, merge

I have two large dataframes. A minimum, reproducible example of them looks like this:

```
A <- data.frame(A=c("a","b","c","d"), B=c(1,2,3,4), C=c(1,2,NA,NA), D=c(1,2,3,4))
A

  A B  C D
1 a 1  1 1
2 b 2  2 2
3 c 3 NA 3
4 d 4 NA 4

B <- data.frame(A=c("c","d"), B=c(3,4), C=c(3,4))
B

  A B C
1 c 3 3
2 d 4 4
```

For every row with a NA in A, I have a corresponding row in B with the replacement of the missing value. I would like to merge the two dataframes A and B to a "common" dataframe AB in a way that the NA's in dataframe A, column C are replaced by their corrsponding value in dataframe B, column C. The result should look like this:

```
AB <- data.frame(A=c("a","b","c","d"), B=c(1,2,3,4), C=c(1,2,3,4), D=c(1,2,3,4))
AB

  A B C D
1 a 1 1 1
2 b 2 2 2
3 c 3 3 3
4 d 4 4 4
```

The "closest" (not so close either) I got to the solution was with the following code:

```
AB <- merge(A,B, all.x = TRUE)
AB

  A B  C D
1 a 1  1 1
2 b 2  2 2
3 c 3 NA 3
4 d 4 NA 4
```

Which, obviously, just uses the variables from A. I have already consulted the follwing questions:

- [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)
- [Merging data frames with different number of rows and different columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35202380/merging-data-frames-with-different-number-of-rows-and-different-columns)

Please consider that the real dataframes are much larger. If you need any further information, please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is C the only column where you need to do replacements, or does this need to scale up to more combinations of columns?

Comment: Thanks for asking. C is the only column where I need to do replacements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `data.table`-package, you can perform an update-join, which should run fast on large datasets.

```
library(data.table)
#set A and B as data.table
setDT(A);setDT(B)
#update col C in data.table A with col C from data.table B, join by cols A and B
A[ B, C := i.C, on = .( A, B) ]
```

**output**

```
#    A B C D
# 1: a 1 1 1
# 2: b 2 2 2
# 3: c 3 3 3
# 4: d 4 4 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this in `base`:

```
index <- match(B$A, A$A) 

A$C[index] <- B$C

# A B C D
#1 a 1 1 1
#2 b 2 2 2
#3 c 3 3 3
#4 d 4 4 4
```

Answer (score -1):

`rbind(data.frame(na.omit(A)), B)`

Comment: It's helpful if you can explain what this does and why it works, but it seems like it misses the purpose of what the OP wants—they aren't looking for just a row-binding, since that will miss the issue of replacement